# How to create a directory using Ansible

Tags: directory, filesystems, ansible

How do you create a directory `www` at `/srv` on a Debian-based system using an Ansible playbook?

Answer (score 866, accepted):

You want the `ansible.builtin.file` module. To create a directory, you need to specify the option `state: directory`:

```yaml
- name: Creates directory
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /src/www
    state: directory
```

You can see other options at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html

Comment: If `state=directory`, all immediate subdirectories will be created if they do not exist, since 1.7 they will be created with the supplied permissions.

Comment: @Alex `all immediate subdirectories` is confusing, could you define that and give an example?

Comment: @JamieJackson There is a mistake, should be "all intermediate subdirectories".

Comment: @Alex Wouldn't it be more clear to say "parent directories"?

Comment: This answer is minimalist and correct, but some consider it a best practice to explicitly declare owner, group and mode. One of the reasons to do this - even when it seems unnecessary - is because over time your current assumptions fail: a distro/release changes and with it come different umask defaults, or ticket databases can be migrated+deleted (losing track of what command-line arguments deployments/installs declared), and maybe you're not available to answer questions anymore.

Comment: If `state` is set to `directory`, and `recursive` is set to `yes`, the intermediate directories will be created. According to the documentation

Answer (score 257):

You can even extend the file module and even set the owner,group & permission through it. (Ref: [Ansible file documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html#file-module))

```
- name: Creates directory
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /src/www
    state: directory
    owner: www-data
    group: www-data
    mode: 0775
```

Even, you can create the directories recursively:

```
- name: Creates directory
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /src/www
    state: directory
    owner: www-data
    group: www-data
    mode: 0775
    recurse: yes
```

This way, it will create both directories, if they didn't exist.

Comment: The `recursive` argument makes this much like using `mkdir -p` (for those googling _ansible mkdir -p_).

Comment: I found that it changes child files permissions also... almost like mkdir -p /foo/bar && chmod -R 0775 /foo/bar.. has anyone else observed this with Ansible 2.0.0.2

Comment: The `recurse` parameter doesn't like `mkdir -p`. It recursively set the specified file attributes (applies only to state=directory). If `state=directory`, all immediate subdirectories will be created if they do not exist, since 1.7 they will be created with the supplied permissions.

Comment: @ThePracticalOne - Yes... using "recurse" behaves exactly the same way `chmod -R` does. That is, if `path` already exists as a dir, and there are files inside it, the `recurse` option will (sometimes unfortunately) also apply those same permissions to the files. This is [by design](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/7839), for better or worse.

Comment: To further expand, if `recurse` option is specified with `owner` or `group`, `chmod -R` (equiv.) will be applied. This will become an issue if there is lots of file.
For me, I had ~200 application versions in a folder, each with ~35k files, which adds up to ~7M files. The chmod will take so long that it timed out the shared SSH connection.

Comment: What @ThePracticalOne one says is still an issue as of Ansible 2.9: the mode for all *files* inside the directory will be set to the mode you specify as well. This makes `recurse: yes` practically useless to me, as I want to specify a directory mode with +x, but I don't want all files inside the directory to be made executable.

Answer (score 33):

Additional for all answers here, there is lot of situations when you need to create more then one directory so it is a good idea to use loops instead creating separate task for each directory.

```yaml
- name: creates multiple directories in one task
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
  loop:
    - /srv/www
    - /dir/foo
    - /dir/bar
```

Answer (score 20):

you can create using:

### Latest version 2<

```
- name: Create Folder
  file: 
    path: /srv/www/
    owner: user 
    group: user 
    mode: 0755 
    state: directory
```

### Older version

```
- name: Create Folder
  file: 
   path=/srv/www/
   owner=user 
   group=user 
   mode=0755 
   state=directory
```

Refer - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html

Answer (score 17):

Directory can be created using file module only, as directory is nothing but a file.

```
# create a directory if it doesn't exist
- file:
    path: /etc/some_directory
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
    owner: foo
    group: foo
```

Answer (score 10):

```html
- name: Create a directory 
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /etc/some_directory
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
```

Answer (score 9):

```
- file:
    path: /etc/some_directory
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
    owner: someone
    group: somegroup
```

That's the way you can actually also set the permissions, the owner and the group. The last three parameters are not obligatory.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a directory. using

```
# create a directory if it doesn't exist
- file: path=/src/www state=directory mode=0755
```

You can also consult 
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html
 for further details regaridng directory and file system.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the statement

```
- name: webfolder - Creates web folder
  file: path=/srv/www state=directory owner=www-data group=www-data mode=0775`
```

Answer (score 3):

Just need to put condition to execute task for specific distribution

```
- name: Creates directory
  file: path=/src/www state=directory
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a directory in windows:

```yaml
- name: create folder in Windows
  win_file:
    path: C:\Temp\folder\subfolder
    state: directory
```

See the [win_file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_file_module.html) module for more information.

Answer (score 3):

```
enter code here 
- name: creating directory in ansible
  file:
   path: /src/www
   state: directory
   owner: foo
```

you can refer to  [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as one of the following ways:

**Example 1: If Parent Directory already exists:**

```
- name: Create a new directory www at given path 
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /srv/www/
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
```

**Example 2: If Parent Directory does not exist:**

```
- name: Create a new directory www at given path recursively
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /srv/www/
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
    recurse: yes
```

Here in Example 2, it will recursively create both directories if they are not present.

You can see the [Official Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html) for further info on `file_module`

Answer (score 2):

to create directory

```
ansible host_name -m file -a "dest=/home/ansible/vndir state=directory"
```

Comment: little bit wrong, but useful if you dont want make PB.
```ansible -b -i /etc/ansible/inv/yaml/ -m file -a "path=/etc/mongod state=directory mode=700 owner=mongod group=mongod" mng```

Answer (score 2):

We have modules available to create directory , file in ansible

Example

```
- name: Creates directory
  file:
    path: /src/www
    state: directory
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the "file" module in this case, there are so many arguments that you can pass for a newly created directory like the owner, group, location, mode and so on.....

please refer to this document for the detailed explanation on the file module...

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html#file-module

remember this module is not just for creating the directory !!!

Answer (score 2):

To check if directory exists and then run some task (e.g. create directory) use the following

```
- name: Check if output directory exists
    stat:
    path: /path/to/output
    register: output_folder

- name: Create output directory if not exists
    file:
    path: /path/to/output
    state: directory
    owner: user
    group: user
    mode: 0775
    when: output_folder.stat.exists == false
```

Comment: There normaly  is no need to check if directory exists, ansible will run the same.Ansible is designed to be indempotent, meaning that repeating same action should lead to same state. Due to that if directory does not exists it will be created, if run a second time it will be kept.

Answer (score 1):

```
---
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Creates directory
      file: path=/src/www state=directory
```

Above playbook will create www directory in /src path.

Before running above playbook. Please make sure your ansible host connection should be set,

"localhost ansible_connection=local"

should be present in /etc/ansible/hosts

for more information please let me know.

Comment: file: path=/src/www state=directory

Answer (score 1):

You can directly run the command and create directly using ansible

```
ansible -v targethostname -m shell -a "mkdir /srv/www" -u targetuser
```

OR

```
ansible -v targethostname -m file -a "path=/srv/www state=directory" -u targetuser
```

Answer (score 1):

Use file module to create a directory and get the details about file module using command  "ansible-doc file"

Here is an option "state"  that explains:

> If `directory`, all immediate subdirectories will be created if they do not exist, since 1.7 they will be created with the supplied permissions.
>   If `file`, the file will NOT be created if it does not exist, see the [copy] or [template] module if you want that behavior.
>   If `link`, the symbolic link will be created or changed. Use `hard` for hardlinks.
>   If `absent`, directories will be recursively deleted, and files or symlinks will be unlinked.
>
> Note that `file` will not fail if the path does not exist as the state did not change.
>
> If `touch` (new in 1.4), an empty file will be created if the path does not
>   exist, while an existing file or directory will receive updated file
>   access and modification times (similar to the way `touch` works from
>   the command line).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to **make a directory** in Ansible.

- name: Create your_directory if it doesn't exist.
  file:
  path: /etc/your_directory

**OR**

You want to give **sudo privileges** to that directory.

- name: Create your_directory if it doesn't exist.
  file:
  path: /etc/your_directory
  mode: '777'

Answer (score 1):

Hello good afternoon team.

I share the following with you.

```
   - name: Validar Directorio
     stat:
       path: /tmp/Sabana
     register: sabana_directorio
   
   - debug:
       msg: "Existe"
     when: sabana_directorio.stat.isdir == sabana_directorio.stat.isdir

   - name: Crear el directorio si no existe.
     file:
       path: /tmp/Sabana
       state: directory
     when: sabana_directorio.stat.exists == false
```

With which you can validate if the directory exists before creating it

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is about creating `/srv/www` path, and your example is about `/tmp/Sabana`, You should try to match your examples to question when possible, and avoid repeating any of the 22 answers.

Comment: This test is only for trace purpose, as documented in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html : If directory, all intermediate subdirectories will be created if they do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I see lots of Playbooks examples and I would like to mention the Adhoc commands example.

$ansible -i inventory -m file -a "path=/tmp/direcory state=directory ( instead of directory we can mention touch to create files)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use file module for this case. Below playbook you can use for your reference.

```
    ---
     - hosts: <Your target host group>
       name: play1
       tasks: 
        - name: Create Directory
          files:
           path=/srv/www/
           owner=<Intended User>
           mode=<Intended permission, e.g.: 0750>
           state=directory
```

Answer (score -2):

To create a directory using Ansible, you can use the file module with the state: directory parameter. Here's an example of how you can do this:

---

```
- name: Create a directory
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Create directory
      file:
        path: /path/to/directory
        state: directory
```

In the above playbook, replace /path/to/directory with the actual path of the directory you want to create.

You can run this playbook using the ansible-playbook command followed by the playbook file name:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

This playbook will create the specified directory on the localhost. If you want to create a directory on a remote host, replace localhost with the appropriate inventory name or IP address, and make sure Ansible is configured to communicate with that host.

Keep in mind that the file module also allows you to set additional parameters such as ownership (owner and group) and permissions (mode) for the directory. You can check the Ansible documentation for the file module to see all available options.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Answer (score -8):

here is easier way.

`- name: create dir
   command: mkdir -p dir dir/a dir/b`

Comment: this is not idempotent.

Comment: @qubsup: with `-p` it is idempotent

Comment: this lacks the option to set ownership and permissions.

Comment: This is a bad practice since there is an ansible module to be used. The `command` module should only be used if no other module is sufficient for the desired task.