# Copy multiple files with Ansible

Tags: ansible

How can I copy more than a single file into remote nodes by Ansible in a task?

I've tried to duplicate the copy module line in my task to define files but it only copies the first file.

Answer (score 176):

You can use the `with_fileglob` loop for this:

```yaml
- copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /etc/fooapp/
    owner: root
    mode: 600
  with_fileglob:
    - "/playbooks/files/fooapp/*"
```

Comment: This approach could help me if I've had all of my files in the same root for copying into remote machine, what about having some files in various directories. For example, I wanna copy 3 files from 3 different directory

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to move all the files from my `/roles/db/files` but I can't get it working with this method. I've tried `with_fileglob: - /roles/db/file/*`  but it won't fine the path

Comment: The big disadvantage with this method is that it flattens the directory structure.

Comment: **Note** that `loop` is recommended over `with_*`, see [Ansible Playbooks - Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html) documentation.

Answer (score 168):

```yaml
- name: copy multiple items
    copy: 
      src: "{{ item.src }}" 
      dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
    loop:
      - src: containerizers
        dest: /etc/mesos/containerizers
      - src: another_file
        dest: /etc/somewhere
      - src: dynamic
        dest: "{{ var_path }}"
```

Comment: Is it possible to have this solution with the `dest` set as a variable?
`{ src: 'containerizers', dest: {{ containerizers }} }`.

Comment: @Gesias, yes. Actually, both sides can be variables: `{  src: '{{ source.var }}', dest: '{{ dest.var }}' }`

Answer (score 56):

Since Ansible 2.5 the `with_*` constructs [are not recommended](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop), and `loop` syntax should be used. A simple practical example:

```yaml
- name: Copy CA files
  copy:
    src: '{{item}}'
    dest: '/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors'
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  loop:
    - symantec-private.crt
    - verisignclass3g2.crt
```

Please note that in many cases a specific list of files would be preferred over globbing (using wildcards). If specific files are not known,  [`with_fileglob` would still be suggested over a `loop` with `lookup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#comparing-loop-and-with).

Comment: On the [page you linked](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop) it explicitly says that `with_*` is **not** deprecated: “We have not deprecated the use of `with_<lookup>` - that syntax will still be valid for the foreseeable future.” (As of 11/2021) They only *recommend* it.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that - the notice was not there before, it was added at some point in late 2019. Will amend the answer accordingly.

Comment: The page linked in this answer gives `with_fileglob` as an example of a `with_*` construct that would be preferred over a `loop`, near the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks, slightly amended the answer to include globbing.

Answer (score 19):

You can use with_together for this purpose:

```
- name: Copy multiple files to multiple directories
  copy: src={{ item.0 }} dest={{ item.1 }}
  with_together:
    - [ 'file1', 'file2', 'file3' ]
    - [ '/dir1/', '/dir2/', '/dir3/' ]
```

Comment: Although it works, this is not semantically clean - there are cleaner options.

Answer (score 15):

If you need more than one location, you need more than one task. One copy task can copy only from one location (including multiple files) to another one on the node.

```
- copy: src=/file1 dest=/destination/file1
- copy: src=/file2 dest=/destination/file2

# copy each file over that matches the given pattern
- copy: src={{ item }} dest=/destination/
  with_fileglob:
    - /files/*
```

Comment: - name: copy file1 
  copy: src=/file1 dest=/destination/file1
- name: copy file2 
  copy: src=/file2 dest=/destination/file2

Comment: Depends. Simpler and likely cleaner, but can be done using more complex data structures, such as a list of anonymous dictionaries with source and target data, looped with_items. It's the same in any language - you have to make a judgment call. There are cases where a delegation function is more efficient and maintainable than a long series of copy/pasted if statements.  I'm that freak that would rather maintain the concise bit of well structured code than a long and tedious list of nearly-identical directives, but I don't assume everyone agrees. Do what's maintainable for you.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a find, and then copy those files.

```yaml
---
- hosts: lnx
  tasks:
    - find: 
        paths: /appl/scripts/inq
        recurse: true
        patterns: "inq.Linux*"
      register: file_to_copy

     - copy: 
         src: "{{ item.path }}" 
         dest: /usr/local/sbin/
         owner: root
         mode: 0775
       loop: "{{ files_to_copy.files }}"
```

Comment: just a side note that `find` module only work for ansible 2.x but not for ansible 1.x

Comment: I have fixed your answer becuase you have mentioned the `stdout_lines` in the return value but is not applicable for `find` module. It only have `files`, `examined` and `matched` as return values. Hope that help others

Comment: Has anybody been able to get this working to copy files to remote nodes? `find` only seems to look at the remote system, not allowing to grab anything from the managing node. These answers, using `with_fileglob`, seems to be more fitting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42290160/272387 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/36720342/272387 .

Answer (score 7):

```
- name: find inq.Linux*
  find:  paths="/appl/scripts/inq" recurse=yes patterns="inq.Linux*"
  register: find_files


- name: set fact
  set_fact:
    all_files:
      - "{{ find_files.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
  when: find_files > 0


- name: copy files
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /destination/
  with_items: "{{ all_files }}"
  when: find_files > 0
```

Comment: A good answer contains not only code, but also some explanations or documentation references.

Comment: The find, set_fact and copy modules are all explained in the ansible documentation. Read about filters, also explained in the ansible documentation if you whant to know more about this section (- "{{ find_files.files | map(attribute'path') | list }}")

Comment: Copy assumes a local source, so to make this example self-consistent, either the find option needs to be run once on localhost, or else the final copy operation needs to specify a remote src. The nice thing about this approach is that it makes the file list available for other purposes (e.g. deleting later if the copy is only temporary).

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use with_items:

```
- copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /etc/fooapp/
    owner: root
    mode: 600
  with_items:
    - dest_dir
```

Answer (score 3):

`copy` module is a wrong tool for copying many files and/or directory structure, use `synchronize` module instead which uses `rsync` as backend. Mind you, it requires `rsync` installed on both controller and target host. It's really powerful, check [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html).

Example - copy files from `build` directory (with subdirectories) of controller to `/var/www/html` directory on target host:

```
synchronize:
  src: ./my-static-web-page/build/
  dest: /var/www/html
  rsync_opts:
    - "--chmod=D2755,F644" # copy from windows - force permissions
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through variable with list of directories:

```
- name: Copy files from several directories
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "/etc/fooapp/"
    owner: root
    mode: "0600"
  loop: "{{ files }}"
  vars:
    files:
      - "dir1/"
      - "dir2/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following source code for copy multiple files on your client machine.

---

```
 - name: Copy data to the client machine
   hosts: hostname
   become_method: sudo
   become_user: root
   become: true
   tasks: 
     # Copy twice as sometimes files get skipped (mostly only one file skipped from a folder if the folder does not exist)
     - name: Copy UFO-Server 
       copy:
         src: "source files path"
         dest: "destination file path"
         owner: root
         group: root
         mode: 0644
         backup: yes
       ignore_errors: true
```

Note:

If you are passing multiple paths by using variable then

src: "/root/{{ item }}"

If you are passing path by using a variable for different items then

src: "/root/{{ item.source_path }}"

Answer (score 2):

**Copy files from multiple directories to multiple directories with Ansible**

I found the [guenhter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39263187/14188658) answer helpful but needed to change also the remote files' mode. I don't have enough reputation to put this as a comment, which would be a more appropriate place for this. In the example, I copy two files from two directories into /tmp and /tmp/bin, which I create first and modify remote files mode.

```
- name: cpldupd
  hosts: test
  remote_user: root
  become: true
  vars:
    - rpth: /tmp
  tasks:
    - name: Create '{{rpth}}/bin'
      file:
        path: '{{rpth}}/bin'
        state: directory

    - name: Transfer
      copy: src={{ item.src }} dest={{ item.dest }} mode=0775
      with_items:
      - { src: '../utils/cpldupd', dest: '{{rpth}}/cpldupd' }
      - { src: '../utils/bin/cpldupd', dest: '{{rpth}}/bin/cpldupd' }
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30961802)

Comment: It's not a question but another more complete example of copying files from multiple directories to multiple directories with Ansible. It adds remote file mode. It could be more appropriate to add it as a comment but I do not have enough reputation yet.  I see that you have also used this technique in the past https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347717/how-to-create-an-empty-file-with-ansible/50005056#50005056

Comment: I was a bit harsh there, sorry: When I was reviewing the question it felt like you were wanting to highlight how to deal with file permissions but that wasn't in the original question (thus a new question could be a good option to highlight this); you're right that a comment feels more appropriate to put against the answer you've mentioned; also I saw that using `mode` was already in several of the other answers so no particular need to say it again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic solution for copying files:

```yaml
   ...
    - name: Find files you want to move
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: /path/to/files/
        file_type: file
        excludes: "*.txt" # Whatever pattern you want to exclude
      register: files_output

    - name: Copy the files
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: "{{ item.path }}"
        dest: /destination/directory/
      loop: "{{ files_output.files }}"
   ...
```

This is more powerful than using `with_fileglob` as you can match using regexes. Here is this play in action:

```
$ ls /path/to/files
demo.yaml  test.sh  ignore.txt

$ ls /destination/directory
file.h

$ ansible-playbook playbook.yaml
...[some output]...

$ ls /destination/directory
file.h demo.yaml test.sh
```

As you can see from the above example, `ignore.txt` was not copied over to the destination directory because of the `excludes` regex in the playbook. Ignoring files like this is not possible as simply using `with_fileglob`.

Additionally, you can move files from multiple directories with relative ease:

```yaml
   ...
    - name: Find files you want to move
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: /path/to/files/
        # ... the rest of the task
      register: list1

    - name: Find more files you want to move
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: /different/path/
        # ... the rest of the task
      register: list2

    - name: Copy the files
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: "{{ item.path }}"
        dest: /destination/directory/
      loop: "{{ list1.files + list2.files }}"
   ...
```

Comment: Please add more details, and add some example.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz as requested 

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a sample Ansible Script to copy multiple Files on remote Hosts**

```yaml
- name: Copy Multiple Files on remote Hosts
  ansible.windows.win_copy:
    src: "{{ srcPath }}/{{ item }}" # Remeber to us {{item}}
                                    # as a postfix to source path

    dest: "{{ destPath }}"
    remote_src: yes # if source path is available on remote Host
  with_items:
    - abc.txt
    - abc.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

---

- hosts: test
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  vars:
  path: '/home/ansibm/playbooks'
  remote_path: '/home/{{ansible_ssh_user}}'
  dir: 'yml_files'
  tasks:

  - name: "creating directory for backup file"
    file:
    path: '{{ remote_path }}/{{ dir }}'
    state: directory
    owner: '{{ansible_ssh_user}}'
    group: '{{ansible_ssh_user}}'
    mode: 0700
  - name: "copying yml files"
    copy:
    src: '{{item}}'
    dest: '{{ remote_path }}/{{ dir }}'
    owner: '{{ansible_ssh_user}}'
    group: '{{ansible_ssh_user}}'
    mode: 0644
    loop:
    - '{{ path }}/ab.html'
    - '{{ path }}/cp.yml'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).