# Copy folder content with Ansible

Tags: ansible

For some weird reasons I'm having troubles with a simple task which is copying a content of the folder `myfiles` (few files in there) to the `dist/myfiles` location. Task looks like this:

```
name: Deploy config files like there is no tomorrow
copy:
  src: "{{ item }}"
  dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user_id }}/dist/{{ item }}"
with_items:
  - 'config'
  - 'myfiles/'
```

`myfiles` folder exist under the `dist` and `config` file is copied to the `dist` folder.

Is this possible in Ansible or I should copy each file separately? Am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: The copy module copies files. It does support some recursive directory copying but is not the best. If you need directories you should try the http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html instead. Note: it needs rsync on the machine to work, which is not installed by default on some distributions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your task copies both: the `config` file and the `myfiles` on Debian and CentOS targets properly.

---

If for some reason you have a problem, you might have a look at [Looping over Fileglobs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/fileglob.html).

You need to split the task into two, with the second one looking like:

```
- name: Deploy multiple config files
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user_id }}/dist/myfiles/{{ item | basename }}"
  with_fileglob:
    - /path/to/myfiles/*
```

For a recursive copy, check [this question on SeverFault](https://serverfault.com/q/649721/197039)

---

Alternatively, you could use the [`synchronize` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html), but pay special attention when using `become`. See [this question on SuperUser](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html).