# ansible.builtin.copy:: how to multiple file copy

Tags: ansible

So, this is ansible 2.10, and i'm trying to copy multiple files using `with_items` and it seems that it does not work. My tryout are more or less on the form of (this is a task):

```
---
- name: Sync md tools
ansible.builtin.copy:
dest: /root/bin/
src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/../additions/mdraid/{{ item }}"
with_items:
- mdadm_readd_dev
- md_check
owner: root
group: root
mode: '0700'
force: yes
```

I'm aware of `ansible.posix.synchronize` and of `src_dir/ dst_dir/` format, but i would like to be able so specify a list. Is there a way to copy a specific list of multiple files with ansible.builtin.copy?

Comment: `it does not work` => can you please define what that means exactly ? Are you really running the example as is ? Because it is not a valid ansible task definition.

Comment: ok, i found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36700613/624734

Comment: Please fix indentation in your question. Your issue looks like you're mixing task keyword `with_items` in the middle of module parameters.

Comment: yup, it was an indentation problem that i finally noticed in my above posted link. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bad syntax, ie. bad indentation. `ansible-lint` or `ansible-playbook <playbook> -C` would tell you more.