# How to create folder with the same name of the inventory file used in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

This is my script:

```yaml
---
- name: Update Red Hat system and lock version
  hosts: "{{host}}"
  become: true
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="Host is {{ ansible_fqdn }}"
    
    - name: install dnf versionlock plugin
      dnf:
        name: dnf-plugin-versionlock
        state: latest

    - name: unlock all packages
      shell: dnf versionlock delete "*"

    - name: Update all packages
      dnf:
        name: '*'
        state: latest
  
    - name: lock all packages
      shell: dnf versionlock add "*"
        
    - name: send list of locked packages to remote host
      fetch:
        src: /etc/dnf/plugins/versionlock.list
        dest: ansible/inventory/dnf_lockFiles/versionlock.list
        flat: yes
```

In the last step I would like to create a folder under `ansible/inventory/dnf_lockFiles/` that has the name of the inventory file.

For example if the inventory being used has the name `test` then the path created would look like this: `ansible/inventory/dnf_lockFiles/test/versionlock.list`.

How do I use the name of the inventory as a variable?

Comment: What do you mean by _"the inventory name"_? Is it the name of the inventory file? Is it the hostname of that host in the inventory? Else?

Comment: As reported by β.εηοιτ.βε, there's no such thing as an inventory name as multiple inventory directories containing multiple inventory files can be used at once. The closest you can get is a list of all inventory sources being currently used inside the variable `ansible_inventory_sources`

Comment: thank you both! it was the name of the inventory file i was after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems you are interested in the name of the inventory file, have a look into the following minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    INVENTORY_FILE_NAME: "{{ ansible_inventory_sources | first | basename }}"

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ INVENTORY_FILE_NAME }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: hosts.ini
```

for [a inventory file of `hosts.ini`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups).

To account for the comment from @Zeitounator

> *The closest you can get is a list of all inventory sources being currently used inside the variable `ansible_inventory_sources`*

the [filter `| first`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) will provide the first list element, and

> *... there's no such thing as an inventory name as multiple inventory directories containing multiple inventory files can be used at once*

the [filter `| basename`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) will provide only the filename from that path.

**Note:** The given example can provide a correct result only if there is no more than one single inventory file.

**Further Documentation**

- [Special Variables - Magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#magic-variables)

---

> *In the last step I would like to create a folder under `ansible/inventory/dnf_lockFiles/` that has the name of the inventory file.*

```yaml
- name: Create directory
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "ansible/inventory/dnf_lockFiles/{{ INVENTORY_FILE_NAME }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to create a directory using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844905/)

Comment: Thank you! this was exactlley what i was loocking for