Change ownership of parent directory chain recursively
I have a target linux node with default umask=0077.
When I run a playbook
- name: Create folder for app
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
    owner: app_user
    mode: 0755
  with_items:
    - "/opt/app/folder1/bin"
    - "/etc/program/folder2"

parameter "mode" is applicable only to the last folder(bin and folder2).
All parent directories got strict rights, according umask.
How can I set required permission to parent directories (not for all /opt or /etc, only for chains):

/opt, /opt/app, /opt/app/folder1, /opt/app/folder1/bin
/etc, /etc/program, /etc/program/folder2


All parent directories got strict rights > No, all parents directory where not created by this task, but pre-existed.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472168/whats-the-easy-way-to-auto-create-non-existing-dir-in-ansible#comment58357861_22483724

No. I have a clean mountpoint /etc and /opt without any folders on a fresh server. After, I set umask in /etc/profile and re-login. Later, I run this playbook and got nested folders, but correct rights are only on the last folder.

If directory, all intermediate subdirectories will be created if they do not exist. Since Ansible 1.7 they will be created with the supplied permissions., my bad, the intermediate subdirectories will be created indeed but with the specified permissions. So, I guess your issues resides in the rights of /etc and /opt directories, which you don't want to change the ownership (maybe the rights, but I even doubt so).

Per default (on my Alpine distro) both /etc and /opt are rx, so they should be readable and traversable by other users, so you should not have any issue there.

Another option is that you first ran your task without the mode and that, now, rerunning it will fix the mode of the last subdirectory but not the intermediate ones

Yea, the main question is how to change rights on all intermediate parent folders without all subfolders:-)

Looks like you are stuck with an old chmod -R here, related: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3141#issuecomment-19075618

Another way, as explained by the creator of Ansiblle there, would be to have you loop set to loop: [/opt/app, /opt/app/folder1, /opt/app/folder1/bin, /etc/program, /etc/program/folder2]

Very bad. I simplified playbook in an example. Really /opt/app/folder1/bin and /etc/program/folder2 are vars like "{{ path1 }}" and "{{ path2 }}"

Q: "Change rights on all intermediate parent folders."
Short answer: The module file doesn't know where to start changing the permissions when all subdirectories exist.
Details: For example, given the paths, declare depth where you want to start changing the rights. In this case, depth=1 is the root directory and depth=2 is /tmp9
  path1: /tmp9/a/b/c
  path2: /tmp9/x/y/z
  depth: 2

Create a file with the loop that incrementally changes the subdirectories
shell> cat subdirs.yml
- file:
    path: "{{ root }}/{{ subs[:ansible_loop.index] | join('/') }}"
    state: directory
    owner: admin
    mode: 0755
  loop: "{{ subs }}"
  loop_control:
    extended: true
  vars:
    dirs: "{{ outer_item | split('/') }}"
    root: "{{ dirs[:depth] | join('/') }}"
    subs: "{{ dirs[depth:] }}"

Include this task in a loop
    - include_tasks: subdirs.yml
      loop:
        - "{{ path1 }}"
        - "{{ path2 }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: outer_item

Given the below tree, the task is idempotent
shell> tree -pu /tmp9
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /tmp9
├── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  a
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  b
│       └── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  c
└── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  x
    └── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  y
        └── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  z

If you change the mode
    mode: 0700

the task changes the permissions
shell> tree -pu /tmp9
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /tmp9
├── [drwx------ admin   ]  a
│   └── [drwx------ admin   ]  b
│       └── [drwx------ admin   ]  c
└── [drwx------ admin   ]  x
    └── [drwx------ admin   ]  y
        └── [drwx------ admin   ]  z



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost
  become: true

  vars:

    path1: /tmp9/a/b/c
    path2: /tmp9/x/y/z
    depth: 2

  tasks:

    - include_tasks: subdirs.yml
      loop:
        - "{{ path1 }}"
        - "{{ path2 }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: outer_item


The module file works as expected. Quoting:

If `directory', all intermediate subdirectories will be created if they do not
exist. Since Ansible 1.7 they will be created with the supplied permissions.

For example, given the empty directory
shell> tree -pu /tmp9
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /tmp9

the play
- hosts: localhost
  become: true

  vars:

    path1: /tmp9/a/b/c
    path2: /tmp9/x/y/z

  tasks:

    - file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: directory
        owner: admin
        mode: 0755
      loop:
        - "{{ path1 }}"
        - "{{ path2 }}"

creates the tree
shell> tree -pu /tmp9
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /tmp9
├── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  a
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  b
│       └── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  c
└── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  x
    └── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  y
        └── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  z

, but changing the mode
        mode: 0700

changes the last subdirectory permissions only
shell> tree -pu /tmp9
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /tmp9
├── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  a
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  b
│       └── [drwx------ admin   ]  c
└── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  x
    └── [drwxr-xr-x admin   ]  y
        └── [drwx------ admin   ]  z



Vladimir,
it is a great solution. I never works with construction like this dirs[:depth]. Thank you!
